# Finding the number of distinct common roots of unity

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations, roots-of-unity

Consider equations:

$${x}^{p} = 1\\ 
{x}^{q} = 1$$

Then the number of common roots is equal to the $\gcd(p,q).$

But, how can I prove this statement?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried making the angles of the common roots equal. (2aπ)/p = (2bπ)/q => a/p = b/q. But, that didn't lead me anywhere

Comment: Put your work in the question.

Comment: Hint: Use [Bézout's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) (This identity is extremely useful for anything that involves the gcd. It is well worth your while to familiarize yourself with it, and why it is true.)

Answer (score -1):

WLOG, assume that $p > q$.
From the division algorithm, we know that $p = aq+b$.
Then,

$$x^p = x^{aq+b} = (x^q)^ax^b = x^b = x^{p\text{ mod }q}.$$

Here, we have condensed the problem from common roots of $x^p$ and $x^q$ to the common roots of $x^p$ and $x^{p\text{ mod }q}$.

Can you see a correspondence to the Euclidean algorithm?

Comment: I don't know much about the Euclidean algorithm

Comment: This would be a good place to start.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm